# Issue with Visual Studio Code and the Python Interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

today when I went to use Visual Studio Code the Python extension was all messed up and does not say I have an interpreter selected. I've tried reinstalling Python and reinstalling VSC but this has not been successful. I can run python files, use `python --version` and `pip --version` in the command line. On VSC, when I clicked the run button it works as intended so I do not think that this issue is in the Python installation. The only time today that it showed an interpreter selected was on the reinstall. It said it was selected and then when I closed the app and reopened it, it went back to the way it was. When I open the menu to select the interpreter it's almost as it is glitching because when I make an arrow key input the menu cursor continuously moves up and down. I also tried installing an older version of the extension and this did not help either. Below is what it looks like when I select the option to select an interpreter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you `cmd` been blocked? `Cmd` is supported on Windows for linting, selection, formatting, and other operations to work. You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17848) for more details.

Comment: I can use command prompt and the python command works in it. I do not think that is the issue.